# Extending the notion of absolute continuity and Fundamental theorem of calculus for Lebesgue integral to multivariable cases

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, absolute-continuity

In "Real Analysis" (1999) by Folland, p.105-106, it is stated that a function $F(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
F(x)=\int^x_{-\infty} f(t)dt
\end{equation}
for some $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is absolutely continuous and $F'=f$ a.e.

I wonder if this result (at least partially) generalizes to multivariable cases. That is, suppose that there exists a null set $E_x \subset \mathbb{R}$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that a function $F(x,y): \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has the relation
\begin{equation}
F(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t,y)dt
\end{equation}
which holds on $\cup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \text{ }(x) \times \bigl[\mathbb{R}-E_x\bigr]$ for some $f(x,y) \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Then, my questions are:

1. Is $F(x,y)$ absolutely continuous with respect to the $x$ variable?
2. Or at least, can we say that $F(x,y)$ has a partial derivative w.r.t $x$ almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\partial_x F = f$ a.e?

Multivariable cases seem to cause some subtle issues regarding almost everywhere equality. Could anyone please clarify?

Comment: See [Radamacher's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) if you are interested in a multivarible soft equivalent for a.s. differentiability.